# Call() acts as if it was Wait()

Tags: c#, botframework

I don't understand why in this code snipet, Call() acts as if it was Wait()

```
private async Task MessageProcessed(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    await context.PostAsync("Hello");

    var infoDialog = FormDialog.FromType<Equipements>();
    context.Call(infoDialog, ResumeAfterEquipementsDialog);
}
```

When I arrive at Call line, I need enter another message on the chanel to make it working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like `var infoDialog = FormDialog.FromType<Equipements>(FormOptions.PromptInStart);` I think the `FormOptions.PromptInStart` is what you're looking for in this case. it tells the bot to prompt the user for the first field to be filled in as soon as the new dialog starts. The constructor you're using resolves that parameter to FormOptions.None, which doesn't prompt